# Using Hyperlink Type ReportExecution in JasperReports Server

Tags: hyperlink, jasper-reports, jasperserver, drilldown

All I want to do is create a Drill down report from say report "one" to report "two"

I can't find ANY documentation or examples on how to use *Hyperlink Type ReportExecution* for *JasperReports Server*

It all seems straight forward but it doesn't work (parameters aren't sent through)

HOW ITS CURRENTLY SETUP:

Target is set to "Self"
Type is set to "ReportExecution"

In reference tab I have correct link (it links to drill-down report successfully)

```
"./flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=%2FNWU%2FStudentInformation%2FCurriculumManagement%2FAPQIBI005drill"
```

Anchor and page tab is empty (have no Idea what to put here since I cant find any Docs on it)

Link parameters have values in that should work but aren't (double checked everything here many times)

```
campusAndFaculty | $P{campusAndFaculty}
campus           | $F{cn_campusname.cn_campusid}
```

Tooltip Tab is empty

**What am I doing wrong? Why aren't the params being sent through?**

NOTE:
Using *JasperReports Server Pro 5.0.1*  &
Using *iReport 5.0.0*

I also know of the sample report (/Reports/Samples/Employee List report.), but our server doesn't have any sample reports

Answer (score 3):

Remove the link from your Reference tab. On the Link parameters tab, add a parameter named

> _report

and set the expression for _report to reflect the path to the target report:

> "/reports/myFolder/myReport"

Remember to include the quotation marks.

Also, it would seem that the Jaspersoft document site is down at the moment, but for future reference you can access the iReport guide here:
http://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation?version=7114

Comment: Awesome thx This works, I only have 1 problem. I cant seem to send through a java.util.Collection type (or java.util.List), The parameter is declared on boath reports and is set to same type everywhere it just shows null

Comment: http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/4620   I could be wrong, but I don't know that you can pass a collection through a hyperlink yet. That was the case in the past, and I can't find anything new online about passing a collection or list through a hyperlink. I searched the bug/feature tracker and I still see that in there. However -- it looks like someone has found a workaround (http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/530801/passing-collection-parameter-drill-down-reports) which might help you.

Comment: And this might be the same guy, but here's another post (http://alexandru-ersenie.com/tag/ireport-collection-parameter/) with a .toString() workaround for passing collections. Scroll down to his November 4, 2009 post. If you figure out how to get it functioning without the workaround, you should post a new question here with the solution -- you would help a lot of people!